# Converting from list of strings to list of list in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, pyspark

I've got a list of PySpark `Row` as:

```
data_list_array = [Row(url='[a,b,c]'),Row(url='[d,b,c]')]
my_list = [(i.url) for i in data_list_array]
print(my_list)
```

returns me

```
['[a,b,c]', '[d,b,c]']
```

But i'm wanting my final data to be as:

```
[['a','b','c'], ['d','b','c']]
```

Is there anyway i can convert from list of strings to list of list ?

Comment: Your final data is not valid python. You need quotes around the strings.

Comment: You *could* do `[x.strip("[]").split(",") for x in my_list]` but it seems like you should fix the problem upstream where `data_list_array` is created. While this works for the specific example posted here, it does not generalize well (suppose the data contained valid commas or square brackets).

Comment: List of list of what? I mean, what do you want to store in the inner lists? Strings? Variables, perhaps?

Comment: Related: [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Comment: @JosuéCortina I'm trying to create a `gensim` Dictionary as shown here: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/corpora/dictionary.html

The only issue i'm facing is pyspark is returning me the list of words as a string like i mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```python
desired_output = [s[1:-1].split(',') for s in my_list]
```